# Using static member templates of a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

Why doesn't this code compile?

```
struct A {
    template <class T>
    static T a(int i) { return 2*i; }
};

template <class T>
struct B {
    double b;
    B(): b(T::a<double>(5)) {}
};

template class B<A>;
```

The compiler doesn't even reach the template instantiation. I'm using gcc 4.7.0.

```
test.cc: In constructor »B<T>::B()«:
test.cc:9:25: Error: expected »(« before »<« token
test.cc:9:26: Error: expected primary-expression before »double«
```

Comment: Maybe you could provide the compiler error message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing a `template` keyword since `a` is a dependent name (or something like that).

```
B(): b(T::template a<double>(5)) {}
```

(Also your last line should be `template struct B<A>;`.)

For the gory details, see: 
[Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: Ah thanks, I always forget about that one.

Comment: Regarding the recommendation for `template struct B<A>`... according to the standard, either one is correct. Sadly some compilers (namely Microsoft's) don't always adhere to the standard.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put `template` before the method name:

```
B(): b(T::template a<double>(5)) {}
```

This is because when the template class `B` is being parsed, the compiler does not know that `T::a` is a templated method (since `T` is not specified until then, and `T::a` is completely unknown), so it doesn't know that `<double>` should be parsed as a template parameter list.

It could also mean and will indeed be parsed as: `T::a` less than `double` greater than `(0)`. Of course, `double` isn't an expression, so this failes; thus the error message. So the compiler *could* just assume that you want it to be a templated function call. But you can also have a non-type template parameter, let's say for example an int, so `T::a<42>(5)` can be parsed as `T::a` less than `42` greater than `(5)`, which isn't a template. But you wanted it to be parsed as `T::a` then a template parameter list with the parameter `42` and then the call-operator with an argument `5`.

To tell the compiler that it's a templated function call, you have to put `template` before the function name.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler knows nothing about T. So every time you write `T::{something}` it assumes, that `{something}` is either a member variable or method of T. If it's not, you have to tell it what it is. You probably know about the `typename` keyword you have to use if what you are referring to is a type and not a variable. There's a similar trick for template members:

```
template <class T>
struct B {
    double b;
    B(): b(T::template a<double>(5)) {}
};
```

Now the compiler knows `a` is a template and that what comes after that is the template parameter list.